# Swift - Overloading Static Methods

Tags: swift, overloading

I have been trying to overload a static method for a public class in Swift 2.

How is that possible? This is similar to what I want to achieve:

```
static func test(message: String) -> Void)?) { ### }

static func test(message: String, number: Int) -> Void)?) { ### }
```

Comment: There are only syntax errors in your question. Drop `)?)` symbols in both methods and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to do exactly, but there are two extra closing parenthesis.  It looks like maybe you're trying to take a closure argument?

If the intent is to take a `String` argument in the first method (and a `String` & `Int` in the second) and return `Void`, then your syntax should look like this:

```
static func test(message: String) { /* implementation */ }

static func test(message: String, number: Int) { /* implementation */ }
```

However, if the intent is to take an optional closure which takes a `String` and returns nothing, then the syntax looks like this:

```
static func test(closure: ((String) -> Void)?) {
    // implementation
}
```

And then if the closure also takes an `Int`:

```
static func test(closure: ((String, Int) -> Void)?) {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I was writing my sample function here in a rush so I added some extra brackets. However what you proposed at the top of your answer is what I've been trying to use, but doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" isn't a description of a problem. @Illinois47 if you want help, you need to provide a lot more detail.